# Xml Serializing form controls after drag and drop - WinForm

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a `Form1` with lots of empty `Panels`.

I have a `Form2` with lots of `UserControls`

I drag and drop the `UserControl` into `Form1` `Panel`

I want to save and load the new `Form1` with a `UserControl` in its `Panel`.

I would like to use XmlSerializer. How exactly could I do it?

Please consider that the form will have multiple `UserControls`, all of different type.

Comment: I would create a panel,put all the UserControls into the panel, and serialize the panel.  I would create a new class MyPanel : Panel that inherits the Net Library Form Panel.  Then in the class have a List<Control> controls where I add the user controls.

Comment: I will give it a try. Would it work if I had all my panels inside a "FlowLayoutPanel"? and serialize that?